# Can not get like of count in restfb

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

i'm getting trouble with how to get count of like in a post and the getcommentcount() with also get the same problem.
i'm try to do like this :

```
Post post = facebookClient.fetchObject("1019734961433937", Post.class);
    long like = post.getLikesCount();
    System.out.print(like);
```

But it's just give me the result 0 .
How can i fix this

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2):

You need to fetch the Likes and Comments object from your post.
If you need only the count you can filter everything and ask for the summary:

```
Post.Likes likes = fbClient.fetchObject(post.getId() + "/likes", Post.Likes.class, 
    Parameter.with("summary", 1), Parameter.with("limit", 0));
long likesTotalCount = likes.getTotalCount();

Post.Comments comments = fbClient.fetchObject(post.getId() + "/comments", Post.Comments.class,
    Parameter.with("summary", 1), Parameter.with("limit", 0));
long commentsTotalCount = comments.getTotalCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            JsonObject jsonObject = facebookClient
                .fetchObject("1019734961433937" + "/likes",
                        JsonObject.class, Parameter.with("summary", true),
                        Parameter.with("limit", 1));
        long count = jsonObject.getJsonObject("summary").getLong(
                "total_count");
        System.out.println("count : "+count);
```

Comment: can you tell me how to get the User infor by rest ?

Comment: `FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);
  User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
  System.out.println("First Name : " + user.getFirstName()
    + " last Name :" + user.getLastName() + "About :"
    + user.getAbout() + "Address :" + user.getAddress() + " mail :"
    + user.getEmail() + " Gender :" + user.getGender());`

Comment: can you tell me if you can get the like of  a page by rest ?

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work.

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("XYZ");
JsonObject jsonObject = facebookClient
           .fetchObject("12345" + "/likes",JsonObject.class, 
            Parameter.with("summary", true),Parameter.with("limit", 0));
```

this result we will get:

```
{"summary":{"total_count":3},"data":[]}
```